# How to remove margin in echarts4r map

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75003209/how-to-have-a-echarts4r-graph-that-fill-all-the-box-shiny-dashboard) post, it's mentioned that we can use `e_grid` to make the charts to fill all the box. However, this solution doesn't work with `e_map` object.

Any solution for this issue?

Tried added `e_grid(0,0,0,0)` but nothing happens.